# lock android to chrome created "app"

Tags: android, google-chrome, shortcut, launcher, kiosk

I have created an "app/shortcut" (I don't know how else to call it) through the Chrome App on an Android tablet.

To ship this tablet to our customers, I want the tablet to be limited to only this shortcut. I don't want the entire Chrome to be opened, as I don't want to have a address bar or whatever visible; just fullscreen.

I have tried several kiosk apps and browser, but unfortunately most of them are build on Chromium, which does not support saving Passwords.

When the system is started, I want my app to be opened and don't want to give an alternative possibility.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just looking for a kiosk browser that is able to pass stored credentials to a web site, the company I work for makes a product which supports that. Take a look at my profile if you'd like more info. I'm very specifically not posting the product here, since it could be interpreted as spam.